# How do I rotate an object back and forth?

Tags: unity

I want my object to rotate between two angles in relation to speed and it doesn't need to be a smooth rotation, how can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please specify what you tried so far abd what's the exat outcome you want with possibly some example numbers. Remember, we don't write the code for you here.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a [pendulum swinging back and forth](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/133191/39518)? If not, please edit your question to clarify. "rotate between two angles in relation to speed" doesn't tell us much, as there's a spectacular array of different relations we could use. Maybe its a spedometer needle, sitting at angleA when at rest and swinging toward angleB as the car accelerates. Or the "speed" is an oscillation speed between the two angles. Or you want this rotation applied to a tail that trails behind an object's movements. Or...