# How to clamp the rotation between two values in unity 3d

Tags: unity, 3d

How can i clamp the rotation of cube between two values and then rotate between them gradually [image]

Details Of what i Want
When I press A or D keys cube should Rotate On Y Axis  from 0 to 13 deg gradually and when key is released cube back to straight position

Comment: [Would any of the answers here suit your case](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130635/how-to-rotate-within-a-fixed-interval-in-unity)? If not, can you edit your question to describe how your case differs from what those solve?

Comment: @DMGregory Ok Done

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to constrain your values, to rotate smoothly, transform.Rotate would do the trick, but the problem comes with orientation, as I see it. You may parent that cube to an object that keeps a fixed orientation, so you rotate the cube as a child. I am asuming you want to rotate on the Y-Axis, so here is an example:

```
public Transform cubeChild;
public float minAngle;
public float maxAngle;
public float rotationSpeed;

void Update()
{
    cubeChild.Rotate(transform.up, (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    cubeChild.rotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3
                                    (
                                        transform.eulerAngles.x,
                                        Mathf.Clamp(transform.eulerAngles, minAngle, maxAngle),
                                        transform.eulerAngles.z
                                    );
}
```

The code is untested, but I'll try it in a couple of minutes to confirm you.